# Using datetime in ASP.NET Core returns http 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

    public ActionResult Session()
    {
        if (TempData["time"] == null)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            endTime = startTime.AddSeconds(120);
            var timeRem = endTime - startTime;
            var nn = timeRem.TotalSeconds;
            TempData["time"] = nn;
        }
        // else
        // {
        //    DateTime refreshTime = DateTime.Now;
        //    var timeRem = endTime - refreshTime;
        //    var nn = timeRem.TotalSeconds;
        //    TempData["time"] = nn;
        // }

        return View();
    }
```

startup code

```
namespace OnlineExam
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
            services.AddIdentity<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = default;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Models.UserAccountModel.OnlineExamDBContext>();

            //services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                           .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExam.Models.AdminQuestionModel.OnlineExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<CandidateLoginDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExam.Models.CandidateExam.CandidateExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddScoped<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.OnlineExamDBContext>();
            //services.AddScoped<OnlineExam.Controllers.AdminQuestionController>();

            //services.AddSession(x => x.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseSession(); //for sessions
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

May I know what mistake I'm making? The code returns a http 500 error. I have a simple text in the view. Still it shows http 500 error. If I delete the datetime code, then the error goes away

Comment: have you tried stepping through it with the debugger? to see where and how it fails? (also: i'm curios as to what your code is actually supposed to be doing, care to explain?)

Comment: `500` means the server (your web app) threw an exception. Just debug your code and check where it throws. In production code you should add proper exception handling and logging

Comment: there are no exceptions thrown atleast in this part of code @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Did you add `Session` support in your middleware configuration?

Comment: yes i did..@haim770

Comment: @Vikas, Show your `Startup.cs`, then

Comment: i removed session code still it shows the error!! @haim770

Comment: @haim770 any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could Figured it Out!!

Tempdata directly does not support storing complex datatypes such as DateTime, var etc. Storing such complex datatypes need to serialized before passing to the view.

In my case i typecasted or converted the datatype to int. Thus fixed the issue.
Here the code

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

    public ActionResult Session()
    {
        if (TempData["time"] == null)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            endTime = startTime.AddSeconds(120);
            var timeRem = endTime - startTime;
            int nn = (int)timeRem.TotalSeconds; //correction line
            TempData["time"] = nn;
        }
        // else
        // {
        //    DateTime refreshTime = DateTime.Now;
        //    var timeRem = endTime - refreshTime;
        //    var nn = timeRem.TotalSeconds;
        //    TempData["time"] = nn;
        // }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: we can store double too.. @stuartd

Comment: But you say you get the error on the line `TempData["time"] =  timeRem.TotalSeconds` and fixed by casting TotalSeconds to an int - but [TotalSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds) **is** a `double`

Comment: Still don't get it. Your answer has the line `int nn = (int)timeRem.TotalSeconds; //correction line` It doesn't really matter anyway.